# Data inser and linking tables

Tags: php, sql, database

I am new in databases but I know how to insert data into one table with sql and php, but now I need to insert data from an array into few tables at the same time. More, I have 3 main tables and 2 linking tables , there is a linkng table between 1 and 2 and another one between 2 and 3. How to insert data into the datables simultaneously? The primary key in linking tables constitute from primary 'id' keys from main tables which are set on auto increment.
Thanks for any help guys..

Comment: After each insert statement you can get the id by calling `mysql_insert_id`. That should help you out.

Comment: You can get better help if you post snippets of relevant code.

Comment: You can use stored procedures to insert data into mysql tables. This approach is specially helpful in these kinds of scenarios.....

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed what do you mean by stored procedures in this case?

Comment: @ TJHeuvel can you give me an examle of how to connect 2 main tables and a linking table betwwen them plz

Comment: @anna: You can declare a stored procedure in the database, passing in all the values that needed to be inserted. Then in that stored procedure, you can insert them in whatever way you like. You can perform multiple inserts in a procedures which will be much more efficient then executing multiple insert statements from php. If you are new to this, then you can follow some tutorials: http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20stored%20procedures%20tutorial

Comment: @TJHeuvel I meant an examlple of how to insert data into two main tables and a linking table using, thnkx

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert records in more than one table at one time. You have to do it once for table manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert data into many tables using one INSERT statement if that's what you mean by simultaneously. Write a series of INSERT statements, one for each table. Do checks to make sure each one has run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert data into table one by one only.
But if you need to guarantee that data exist in all tables at once you should use transaction.
It will help if something is getting wrong and you don't get inconsistent data in db.
For example, in php you make it like this one:

```
$pdo_con = new PDO(...);
try {
$pdo_con->beginTransaction();

$pdo_con->exec("INSERT INTO table1 ....");
$table1_id = $pdo_con->lastInsertId();
$pdo_con->exec("INSERT INTO table2 ....");
$table2_id = $pdo_con->lastInsertId();
$pdo_con->exec("INSERT INTO linked_table .... values($table1_id, $table2_id )");
//repeat for other tables

$pdo_con->commit();
catch(PDOException $e) {
$pdo_con->rollback();
}
```

Comment: thanks for this answer!!!can you tell me what happens if lets say adress already exists in an address table? is it going to take previously established address_id and take it to a lnking table or what?

Comment: :can I use $pdo_con if I have realtional database not object oriented?

Comment: Sure. PDO is only wrapper on different drivers which are used for interaction with db server. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Comment: Regarding previous comment, if you try to insert a record in table with the same unique key(address in this this case) you will get db error. So for catching this situation try to select data from table by this address and then only start to make inserts in appropriate tables.